# How to track Keywords on Google AdWords using UTM Tags

Tags: php, google-ads-api, keyword-search

I am taking over a project from another developer that was not entirely finished and I am lost trying to figure out why the source and medium are being documented but not the keywords.  The medium and source are shown in the url and as hidden fields in a form, but the keywords are not.  This is the part of the code that I believe does what I intend to do.

```
//parse the cookies
var source = _uGC(z, 'utmcsr=', '|');
var medium = _uGC(z, 'utmcmd=', '|');
var term = _uGC(z, 'utmctr=', '|');

// Populate form fields
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#Field113").attr("value", source);
  $("#Field115").attr("value", medium);


  // If there's a "SearchKeyword" URL param, use it for the 'term'
  var SearchKeyword = (location.search.split('SearchKeyword=')[1]||'').split('&')[0];
  if ( (SearchKeyword && !term) || (SearchKeyword && term == "") ) {
    $("#Field126").attr("value", term);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe he cant get keywords?
You can take it from [valuetrack](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/6305348?hl=en)